# How to loop through xml nodes and recreate the xml structure

Tags: xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

I have this XML node:

```
<partyIdentification>
                <id>123</id>
                <schemeId>1111</schemeId>
                <!--GlobalIDs start from here-->
                <id>1234567</id>
                <schemeId>0011</schemeId>
                <id>7654321</id>
                <schemeId>0022</schemeId>
                <id>98765432</id>
                <schemeId>0033</schemeId>
                <id>13680123</id>
                <schemeId>0044</schemeId>
            </partyIdentification>
```

I need to loop through these and recreate the structure like this:

```
<partyIdentification>
                <ID sid="1111">123</id>
                <GlobalID sid="0011">1234567</GlobalID>
                <GlobalID sid="0022">7654321</GlobalID>
                <GlobalID sid="0033">98765432</GlobalID>
                <GlobalID sid="0044">13680123</GlobalID>
</partyIdentification>
```

**Please note**: id and schemeId are linked to each other. So, if there is a schemeID after id, then those are grouped together, as you can see in expected result.
So, anything which comes before the comment: "**GlobalIDs start from here**" should be added to the field <ID and in attribute sid, there can be multiple before this comment.
And, whatever comes after the comment "**GlobalIDs start from here**" should go in <GlobalID and in sid attribute.

I tried many things, for example exsl:node-set and also preceeding and following sibling:

```
<xsl:template match="partyIdentification/id[following-sibling::comment()[1]]">
        <xsl:variable name="IDs">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="IDsRestructuring">
            <xsl:for-each select="$IDs/id">
                <id sid="{following-sibling::schemeId[1]}"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></id>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($IDsRestructuring)/id">
        <ID schemeID="{@sid}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></ID>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you.  In your desired output your beginning and ending tags do not match.  But this does.

```
<xsl:template match="partyIdentification">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- Select the schemeId before the coment. -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="comment()/preceding-sibling::schemeId" mode="FirstschemeId"/>
    <!-- Select the schemeId after the coment. -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="comment()/following-sibling::schemeId"/>  
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Use mode for the first schemeID -->
<xsl:template match="schemeId" mode="FirstschemeId">
  <xsl:element name="ID">
    <xsl:attribute name="sid">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::id[1]"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Do not use mode for after the first schemeID. -->
<xsl:template match="schemeId">
  <xsl:element name="GlobalID">
    <xsl:attribute name="sid">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::id[1]"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I apologies for the wrong closing tags, I have now edited that. I think those were left out in a hurry as this is first time I am on this platform.

Comment: So I edited the answer to handle more schemeId before the comment.  This should solve the problem.  On this platform click the up triangle need to the answer you like next to answer you like to accept it.  Cheers!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative for the answer of [John Ernst](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73109252/3710053)

You could also use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="partyIdentification">
    <!-- Since we need to use the comment more than once, lets put in a variable -->
    <xsl:variable name="commentSplitter" select="comment()[.='GlobalIDs start from here']"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Select all preceding-siblings with the explicit elemName: `ID` -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$commentSplitter/preceding-sibling::schemeId">
        <xsl:with-param name="elemName" select="'ID'"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <!-- Select all following-siblings without a explicit elemName and use the default in that template -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$commentSplitter/following-sibling::schemeId"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  
  
  <!-- Just one template dealing with both element-names, to reduce redundant coding -->
  <xsl:template match="schemeId">
    <xsl:param name="elemName" select="'GlobalID'"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">
      <xsl:attribute name="sid">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::id[1]"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What If I have more segments just before the comment (GlobalIDs start from here), e.g. 
<id>123</id>
<schemeId>1111</schemeId>
<id>456</id>
<schemeId>2222</schemeId>
<id>789</id>
<schemeId>3333</schemeId>

These should be added in ID field not in GlobalID field. I also mentioned in the description:"there can be multiple before this comment". The comment will always come, "GlobalIDs start from here" this is the indicator which tells us that now these are GlobalID values and not ID values.

Comment: I need to read more carefully....I adjusted the solution